# How to create a letter svg with path?

Tags: svg

[image]

This is a letter B and here is the path code

```
<path
  d="M45.691667,45.15 C48.591667,46.1 50.691667,48.95 50.691667,52.2 C50.691667,57.95 46.691667,61 40.291667,61 L28.541667,61 L28.541667,30.3 L39.291667,30.3 C45.691667,30.3 49.691667,33.15 49.691667,38.65 C49.691667,41.95 47.941667,44.35 45.691667,45.15 Z M33.591667,43.2 L39.241667,43.2 C42.791667,43.2 44.691667,41.85 44.691667,38.95 C44.691667,36.05 42.791667,34.8 39.241667,34.8 L33.591667,34.8 L33.591667,43.2 Z M33.591667,47.5 L33.591667,56.5 L40.191667,56.5 C43.691667,56.5 45.591667,54.75 45.591667,52 C45.591667,49.2 43.691667,47.5 40.191667,47.5 L33.591667,47.5 Z" />
```

How Can I change the letter B to letter N ?

Comment: Might be worth using something like vectr.com for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="261.021" height="298.536" viewBox="0 0 261.021 298.536"><g transform="translate(-238.695 -107.379)"><text transform="translate(293 324)" fill="#63ffda" font-size="200" font-family="SegoeUI-Semibold, Segoe UI" font-weight="600"><tspan x="0" y="0">N</tspan></text><path d="M435.651,850.174l126.064-68.158V637.388L437.036,563.135,310.695,632.124V776.474Z" transform="translate(-67 -450)" fill="none" stroke="#63ffda" stroke-width="10"/></g></svg>
```

You can use Adobe XD to create shapes and then export it as SVGS. The color for the backround is #0C1A2E
Here is the
[codepen](https://codepen.io/LightningWizard/pen/jOWevRW)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<text>` component inside the `<svg>`.Then, all you need is set some styles to you text. Something like this:

```
<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<title>Loader Logo</title>
<g>
  <text
    id="B"
    x="50%"
    y="50%"
    textAnchor="middle"
    dominantBaseline="middle"
    fill="currentColor"
    fontWeight="bold"
    fontSize="46px"
  >
    N
  </text>
  <path
    stroke="currentColor"
    strokeWidth="5"
    strokeLinecap="round"
    strokeLinejoin="round"
    d="M 50, 5
              L 11, 27
              L 11, 72
              L 50, 95
              L 89, 73
              L 89, 28 z"
  />
</g>
```